# Footer gap appears when little content

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

So I'm really confused.. my websites footer sits perfectly on the homepage, however as soon as you load content into it for the other pages (via jquery) the footer instantly gains a huge gap at above it.. It isn't until I fill it with loads of text that it finally starts to fill the gap and not keep pushing the gap further and further down the page.

http://colourednoise.co.uk/site/22/ (please note only "Home, What We Do & Sites" work on the navigation)

I know the coding is really messy, but surely it makes no sense.. why is there a threshold to get past before that gap stops appearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the setting below:

```
#holen_wrapper {
    width: 922px;
    /* height: 100%;    */
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: I had attempted something similar to that, however just tried what you said though and it's still the same.

Comment: Did you clear the browser's cache to force reloading everything?

Comment: yes, I also checked the web source to check that it was running the correct code. I guess I might just try recoding the footer, however checking that it works for every step of the way incomplacence with each web page. Thank you anyway!